VS Code react-bootstrap quick import and snippet not showing
Why is my react-bootstrap snippets suddenly not showing? I was working on a project with React JS and the react-bootstrap element suggestions are displaying fine. However just recently, it stopped working. As seen on the picture below

Now any react-bootstrap element I type is not showing and I can't quick import it. It reduces coding speed and productivity since I have to import it manually. Any ideas on how to fix this? All of my VS code extensions are updated as well VS Code itself.
